# "На первом фото" или "на первой фото"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно сочетать порядковое числительное с существительным среднего рода?
"На первом фото" или "на первой фото"?

Answer (score 1):

Перв**ое** фото (ср. род, имен. падеж) -> на перв**ом** фото (предл. падеж - средний род числительного сохраняется независимо от падежа).

Перв**ая** фотография (ж. р., им. п.; неф. разг. "фотка") -> на перв**ой** фотографии ("фотке"; предл. падеж).